# How to fetch the currently selected row in the uipickerview when tapped Done ( having multiple pickers)

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview

I have got `UIPickerview` in my application working fine.

I want to change the default selection behavior of the `UIPickerview`, i mean i have a done button in the `UIToolbar`. The toolbar is added to the `UIPickerview`.

Whenever the user taps on the "Done" button, I want to consider the highlighted entry as selected.
That means user can move up and down , when the user taps on the "Done" button, i want to consider the selection now

Please let me know , how can I fetch the currently selected row for the `UIPickerview` when tapped "Done" button

***Note: I have 3 pickers in my view ( i mean i want to have pickerview tag and pickerview selected row)***

Comment: It's a duplicate post. In SO itself,it has been asked so many times..!!

Comment: @Sarah: If it's a duplicate, you should post the link. Even if you don't have close vote privileges yet, others do. They'll see your suggestion, decide if it's a duplicate, and cast their own votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//Suppose you have created three picker views as firstPickerView, secondPickerView and ThirdPickerView

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(pickerView == firstPickerView)
    {
        NSString *strFirstPickerView = [yourarray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else if(pickerView == secondPickerView)
    {
        NSString *strSecondPickerView = [yourarray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *strThirdPickerView = [yourarray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *str = [yourarray objectAtIndex:row];   
}
```

now str have a selected value. so you can use it when done button press.

Answer (score 2):

selectedRowInComponent:

```
- Returns the index of the selected row in a given component.
- (NSInteger)selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

Parameters
**component**
A zero-indexed number identifying a component of the picker view.
**Return Value**
A zero-indexed number identifying the selected row, or -1 if no row is selected.

[For Help](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html)

And to make a difference between different pickerViews add tag to each of the pickers:

```
 self.pikcerView.tag = 1;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Following example for the UIPickerview controller

.m files here

```
#import "SingleComponentPickerViewController.h"
@implementation SingleComponentPickerViewController
@synthesize singlePicker;
@synthesize pickerData;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

-(IBAction)buttonPressed1
{
    NSInteger row = [singlePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    NSString *selected = [pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                       @"you selected %@!", selected];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                   message : @"Thank you for choosing."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                         cancelButtonTitle :@"Welcome"             
                                         otherButtonTitles :nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    [title release];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {


    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"iPhone",@"iPad",@"iPod",@"iMac",@"Mac",
                      @"iBook",@"Safari",nil];
    self.pickerData = array;
    [array release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [singlePicker release];
    [pickerData release];
    [super dealloc];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [pickerData count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
            titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
           forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
    return[pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
}


@end
```

and .h file here

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SingleComponentPickerViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *singlePicker;
    NSArray *pickerData;
}
@property(nonatomic , retain) UIPickerView *singlePicker;
@property(nonatomic , retain) NSArray *pickerData;

-(IBAction)buttonPressed1;

@end
```

happy coding
@samuel